# Discard ParseQuery results and reload data from pin

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm having trouble with Parse queries and pinned data.

I have some pinned objects in my application, so the user can access offline. At some point of my application, I query for results on the Internet. Then, when the query return the new data, because I've enabled local datastore, this new results are merged to the pinned data until I restart de application. If I pin this new data, it gets persisted obviously even if I restart the application, but I don't want to pin this new data.

What happens is that I want to discard the data from the results from Internet, and query the data from my pinned local datastore because I want to work with the old data.

Is any possibility to requery the objects from pinned data and discard the data form the Query from Internet? Because I don't pin this new data from Internet, the pinned data already exists somewhere. That's why when I kill the app and start it again, the new data from Internet is cleared and I can continue working with the old data from pin.

My problem is that some ParseObjects contains files that I save on a folder with the name of the ParseFile url. When new data comes from Internet, and my ParseObjects get updated, the file url changes and the app cannot access the file on the local folder anymore while offline. Could be useful to alternate with queried data and pinned data, or just revert queried data to pinned data.

Anyone knows if it's possible to do this or knows another workaround to pin data with files correctly?

For me it's not a good solution to query for objects and download the files, because the app might need to download lots of files and this should be done only in Wi-Fi and not automatically. That's why I want to revert the new data to the old one, to continue working offline, until the device has Wi-Fi and can download all the new ParseObjects with its ParseFiles.

Thanks a lot!